# DateTime.TryParse to other culture info

Tags: c#, date

I currently have a time reporting project where you enter a date and report time for that date, ( all the dates are shown and sent back to the backend in swedeish format etc `yy-mm-dd`) 
But if I have another culture info on my computer like `dd-mm-yyyy` it will parse the date wrong and it won't work.

This is my code

```
DateTime reportDate;
if (!DateTime.TryParse(result, out reportDate))
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("Date", "Felaktikt datum");
}
```

This will take my `yy-mm-dd` and parse it to `dd-mm-yyyy` because that's what my computer is set to.

Comment: "all the dates are shown and sent back to the backend in swedeish format etc yy-mm-dd" - why? I suggest you look at `DateTime.TryParseExact` and specify the culture there, if you really have to - but using a human-culture date format for machine-to-machine communication is a really bad ida.

Comment: DateTime.TryParseExact(result, formats,  new CultureInfo("sv-SE""), DateTimeStyles.None, out reportDate)

Comment: Because it's what I were told to do, the dates should be shown yy-mm-dd.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can specify the Swedish culture like this:

```
DateTime reportDate;

if (!DateTime.TryParse(result,
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("sv-SE"),
    System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out reportDate))
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("Date", "Felaktikt datum");
}
```

Comment: reportDate still holds dd-mm-yyyy.

Comment: reportDate is the parsed date, so you can format it how you like. The code above will parse a date like "15-08-28" and turn it into the correct DateTime.

Comment: Solved it by adding                 Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("sv-SE");

Comment: @JoakimCarlsson that's not related - you've just changed how it's *formatted* by default, which has nothing to do with the parsing. `DateTime` doesn't hold any formatting information.

Answer (score 8):

[DateTime.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9h21f14e.aspx) has an extra 2 parameters, the second is [IFormatProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider.aspx) which you can specify which culture you want it to be representing. In your case it's `sv-SE` which is Sweden.

```
DateTime.TryParse(
    result,
    new CultureInfo("sv-SE"),
    DateTimeStyles.None,
    out reportDate
);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try with the second overload of TryParse method

```
DateTime.TryParse(result, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("sv-SE"), DateTimeStyles.None, out reportDate )
```